# Parallax scroll fixed header

Tags: scroll, header, css-position, parallax

I have a problem with my parallax scrolling website. I need to create a fixed header at the top of the site, but it wont remain "fixed".

Link to full code here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ressy0101/sx4ukc1c/5/

```
#header{
 position: fixed;
 background-color: black;
 height: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 9999;
 color:white;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:40px;
}
```

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35958375/css-make-div-position-fixed-inside-div-with-perspective-propertie/

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me, hope it will resolve your issue.

change `position:sticky;`

& add

```
top:0px;
```

i.e

```
#header{
     top:0px;
     position:sticky;
}
```

Comment: sticky is a recent addition and is not supported by most browsers yet https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position#Browser_compatibility