# CSS make DIV position fixed inside DIV with PERSPECTIVE propertie

Tags: html, css

i have a problem for getting `#fixed` with `position:fixed` relative to `#container`

check this fiddle out : https://jsfiddle.net/a1zoghs0/2/

i know that, if i put `#fixed` outside of `#container`,

it will had `position:fixed`. just like this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/xc879rbm/1/

but unluckly, i have an issue where this method can't working. is it 
possible to put this inside `#container` and still enable `position:fixed` relative to `#container`?

is there anything wrong with my code?

thanks in advance...

Comment: What's the issue with having it outside the container?

Comment: when i'm creating javascript overlay function with position:fixed to center, it's not fixed to #container. it cause crash. it's ugly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Since you can't have the `fixed` inside, [Why does perspective changes fixed position in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386038/why-does-perspective-changes-fixed-position-in-css), I suggest you add an extra wrapper for your javascript overlay function.</strike>

Since you can't have the `fixed` inside, [Why does perspective changes fixed position in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386038/why-does-perspective-changes-fixed-position-in-css), just place them outside your container (as in below sample), as I can't see the point adding a second wrapper because the fixed div is relative to the window anyway.

```css
#container {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 perspective:300px;
  perspective-origin:50% 50%;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}

.parallaxBase {
    width:100%; 
    position:absolute; top:200px; left:50%;
    transform:translateZ(0);
   transform:translateX(-50%);

 }

.parallaxBack {
    height:100vh;
    transform:translateZ(-300px) scale(2);

}

#background {background:red; height:200px; padding-top:100px; }
#content {background:yellow; }
#fixed {background:green; 
  width:100%; height:40px; position:fixed; z-index:1; top: 0; left: 0;
 }

#overlay {
width:200px; height:200px; background:purple;
position:fixed; top:50%; left:50%; transform:translate(-50%, -50%); }
```

```html
<div id="fixed">this is fixed // why not fixed?</div>
<div id="container">
  <div class="parallaxBack">
    <div id="background"> this is parallax</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallaxBase">
    <div id="content">
      this is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is content
      this is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="overlay">
  this is overlay
</div>
```

Comment: thanks LGSon for answering my question. this is the issue with overlay  : https://jsfiddle.net/a1zoghs0/3/ it's not centering.

Comment: @ChingChing Updated my answer how to fix that. You just put the overlay outside the container, as you do with the fixed div

Comment: thanks LGSon really appreciate that. so, there is no way to solve this issue with put #overlay inside #container?

Comment: @ChingChing Not if you want it to stay center no matter the container size/scroll position. You can of course use script and calculate the position, though the suggested way is 10 time better, IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution. I'm not exactly sure of all math details in it, but it looks quite robust to resizing of the window.

The main trick is to put the header so far away and make it so big, that movements of the viewport do not affect it's position much - think about moon on the sky, which is big and far away, and thus your movements of the head do not affect it's position.

```css
body{
  margin:0; /* without it your container will not cover full body */
}
#container {
    width:100vw; /* probably 100% would be ok here */
    height:100vh; /* 100% would not be ok here, 
                     as we need to center perspective viewport 
                     w.r.t. screen- not w.r.t. whole long page content */
    /* this makes math easier to me */
    perspective:1px; 
    perspective-origin:0 0;
    /* we want container to be a window through which you watch
       the scrolling world */
    overflow-y:scroll;
    /* we don't want scrollbar at the bottom, as it would again force
       us to use calc for perspective-origin-y.
       Frankly, I do not know why the scrollbar appears at all */
    overflow-x:hidden;
    /* This is to allow positioning of layers relatively to container*/
    position:relative;
}

.parallaxBase {
    width:100%; 
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;  
 }

.parallaxBack {
    height:100vh;
    /* The general formula to keep size intact is scale(perspective-z)
       so in our case it is scale(1+1) */
    transform:translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
}

#background {background:red; height:200px; padding-top:100px; }
#content {background:yellow; }
#fixed {background:green; 
  width:100%; 
  height:40px; 
  /* this is not so much to make it sticky,
     it is rather to not push the parallaxBack div lower,
     and to make sure that header is not occluded by elements
     which have position:absolute like parallaxBase,
     as even z-index:1 won't help you if you have position:static
      */
  position:absolute; 
  top:0px; 
  z-index:1;
  /* Now the main idea:
     we push the navbar 1023px to the back, but at the same time,
     we make it (1023+1) times bigger, which makes it appear in
     original size.*/
  transform: scale(1024) translateZ(-1023px);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="fixed">this is fixed // why not fixed?</div>
  <div class="parallaxBack">
    <div id="background"> this is parallax</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallaxBase">
    <div id="content">
  this is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is content
  this is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is contentthis is content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You might want to play with it in https://jsfiddle.net/7L8ndtuv/2/

I also recommend reading https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/custom-scrollbar which inspired my answer.

Comment: The only problem, in Safari the fixed element is not in the front of others, as well as the page has huge height.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the wrapper (the `div#container` box) around the element of which you want to have a fixed position overrules its effect by the next css property:

```
perspective: 300px;
```

This is the culprit. When you check the documentation of it, it mentions the next line:

> Using this property with a value different than 0 and none **creates a new stacking context**. [source: MDN - CSS perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/perspective)

The use of `position: fixed` has the same behavior, which leads to conflicts.

> *fixed* Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled. When printing, position it at that fixed position on every page. This value **always create a new stacking context**. [source: MDN - CSS position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values)

When you remove the above line, you will see that the element is now fixed to the viewport. But that would ruin your parallax background ...

The only solution to solve it is to add an another container on the top of it and use a separate div for your fixed element.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="fixed">this is fixed // why not fixed?</div>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="parallaxBack">
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And use the `position: fixed` rule on your `div#fixed`.

Comment: thanks KarelG  for answering my question. i just know that. this is my problem with overlay  : https://jsfiddle.net/a1zoghs0/3/ it's not centering.

Comment: @ChingChing : check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1zoghs0/5/) Look to the adaptions i've made in the HTML (added a wrapper around it) and modified two lines in CSS (they're commented by `// ...` ). Is this what you want ?

Comment: thanks KarelG, i appreciate that. i want #overlay position:fixed just like #fixed. if i scroll into it. #overlay keep moving

Comment: @ChingChing the rule apply same here as at `div#fixed`. Since your `#overlay` is inside a container that has `perspective`, the `position: fixed` would not work. You have to keep it outside the `container` element.

Comment: I can't see the point adding an extra wrapper, as a fixed div is relative to the window anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed` is relative to the window and not a parent element. If you want to fix an element in a parent element, make the parent element `position:relative` and the element, you want to fix `position:absolute;top:0px;`.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Please try to describe it anew. What is it, that you would like the #fixed to do?

Comment: i want it position:fixed while scrolling just like this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xc879rbm/1/ but #fixed must be inside #container

Comment: That does not really make much sense. When you set the position of an element to 'position:fixed', you tell the browser to disregard it's hierarchical relation to any other element, and to position it on a fixed spot in the browser window. When an element has 'position:fixed', it is no longer positioned inside any other element, but fixed in the browser window.